Definition of initial value problem
I'm unsure if the definition of 'initial value problem' and 'Cauchy problem' are one and the same, making them interchangeable, or if they posses different properties.

Please provide more information: what are the definitions you are talking about? Why do you think they are equivalent? Why not?

Yes, that's also what I gathered by looking at the definitions provided by Wikipedia.
I wanted to check with the community if such a definition was a universal truth, 'cause I heard both used interchangeably in the course of my bachelor's degree. Especially because we used the term 'Cauchy problem' while stating the Peano and Picard theorems, while most books utilise the term 'initial value problem'.
It was probably an overview by the professor, right?
